# Load Both Image and Text in android

Tags: android, image, button, text

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.jatin.foreignlanguagefinal.French.FrenchFacts">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageFact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:src="@drawable/booksf" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textFact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageFact"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="200"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="France is the world's most popular tourist destination – some 83.7 million visitors arrived in France, according to the World Tourism Organization report published in 2014, making it the world's most-visited country."
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextFact"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textFact"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:text="Next" />
</RelativeLayout>

public class FrenchFacts extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> facts;
ImageView imageFacts;
TextView textFacts;
Button nextFact;
Map<String,Integer> mapFacts;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_french_facts);

    imageFacts = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageFact);
    textFacts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFact);
    nextFact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextFact)

    mapFacts = new HashMap<>();
    mapFacts.put("France is the world's most popular tourist destination – some 83.7 million visitors arrived in France, according to the World Tourism Organization report published in 2014, making it the world's most-visited country.",R.drawable.frances1);
    mapFacts.put("France is the largest country in the EU, and known as 'the hexagon' – with an area of 551,000 sq km it's almost a fifth of the EU’s total area, and due to its six-sided shape France is sometimes referred to as l’hexagone. About a quarter is covered by forest; only Sweden and Finland have more.",R.drawable.frances2 );
    mapFacts.put("Louis XIX was the king of France for just 20 minutes, the shortest ever reign – he ascended to the French throne in July 1830 after his father Charles X abdicated, and abdicated himself 20 minutes later in favour of his nephew, the Duke of Bordeaux.",R.drawable.frances3);
    mapFacts.put("Liberté, égalitié, fraternité meaning ‘liberty, equality and fraternity’ (or brotherhood) is the national motto of France – it first appeared around the time of the Revolution (1789–1799), and was written into the constitutions of 1946 and 1958. Today you’ll see it on coins, postage stamps and government logos often alongside ‘Marianne’ who symbolises the ‘triumph of the Republic’.",R.drawable.frances4);
    mapFacts.put("The French Army was the first to use camouflage in 1915 (World War I) – the word camouflage came from the French verb ‘to make up for the stage’. Guns and vehicles were painted by artists called camofleurs.",R.drawable.frances5);
    mapFacts.put("In France you can marry a dead person – under French law, in exceptional cases you can marry posthumously, as long as you can also prove that the deceased had the intention of marrying while alive and you receive permission from the French president.",R.drawable.frances6);
    mapFacts.put("France was the first country in the world to ban supermarkets from throwing away or destroying unsold food – since February 2016, shops must donate wastage to food banks or charities.",R.drawable.frances7);
    mapFacts.put("The Académie Française has aimed to preserve the French language since 1634 – by attempting to ban, somewhat unsuccessfully, foreign words such as blog, hashtag, parking, email and weekend. It was started by a small group of French intellects and officially recognised by Louis XIII in 1635.",R.drawable.frances8);
    mapFacts.put("At least 40 percent of the music on private radio stations must be of French origin – since 1996, the country’s top media regulator the Conseil Supérieur de L’Audiovisuel (CSA) has been charged with enforcing this French law. The CSA also requires half of the French music quota to be less than six months old.",R.drawable.frances9);
    mapFacts.put("France legalised same-sex marriage in 2013 – when President Françoise Holland signed the bill into law on 18 May 2013, France became the ninth country in Europe and 14th in the world to legalise same-sex marriage.",R.drawable.frances10);

nextFact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Random random = new Random();

            int color = Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256));
            //String holder = facts.get(random.nextInt(facts.size()));
            textFacts.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());





            for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : mapFacts.entrySet()) {
                String text = entry.getKey();
                textFacts.setText(text);


                textFacts.setTextColor(color);

                int image = entry.getValue();

                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(image)
                            .into(imageFacts);


            }

        }


    });
```

I have a imageview, textview and button.
On button click, different images AND text should be displayed. 
I have tried using hashmap, but while iterating, the button click only works once. After that no matter what image and text do not change. So,please tell me what other way could i display text and image.

PS: I have searched the net a lot and couldn't find the answer. Please comment the solution and code in detail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Why are guys down voting the comment. I just said I searched for solution everywhere, but couldn't find it. Why can't you guys simply give me solution. Tell me what I am doing wrong. Give me the reason for down voting.

Comment: It wasn't me :P But please describe your problem more detailed and **provide your Java code**, that you have so far. How many Views are there? I see only one each in your Layout? Or are you talking about a ListView? What do you mean by displaying? They should already be visible from your layout! What exactly is it, that you want to do. Describe your problem more specificly. It's very unclear!

Comment: May be your image and text is changes with last content of your map object. As on each click you iterate through the map and when the loop completes you get same result. I think it will be better to choose random pick option to get the changes.

Comment: @Locdoc01 Sorry, if I was unclear. My Java code is below the layout code. I didn't know how to separate them. So, I am trying to make a facts app, which has three elements on layout. An Image, a text and a button. On click of a button both the image and text should change. I had taken a HashMap<String, Integer>. The string stores the text and the Integer stores the image. Then I tried to iterate the hashmap,on the button click, and stores key in string and value in int variable. Then I displayed both string and int in their respective layout.But on click i can only see one entry from the map.

Comment: @MdSufiKhan How can I implement random pick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

```
 nextFact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int color = Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256));

        textFacts.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        int i = random.nextInt(mapFacts.size());
        Object[] keys = map.keySet().toArray();
        String text = (String) keys[i];
        int id = mapFacts.get(keys[i]);
        textFacts.setText(text);
        textFacts.setTextColor(color);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(id).into(imageFacts);
    }
});
```

Comment: Android studio is saying it cannot resolve getValue() and getKey() symbols.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your answer was really helpful.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `for` loop as it is reflecting only last content of map every time you click button although it is going through all the items but it is happening so fast that you can't find a change. Create a random number to chose from map `index` as you did to chose `color` of text.

```
    nextFact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int color = Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256));
            //String holder = facts.get(random.nextInt(facts.size()));

            textFacts.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

            int index = random.nextInt(mapFacts.size());
            int image = getEntryByIndex(mapFacts,index).getValue();
            String text = getEntryByIndex(mapFacts,index).getKey();
            textFacts.setText(text);
            textFacts.setTextColor(color);
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image).into(imageFacts);
        }
    });
```

You need to make a function that will give you the entry set of map by index and call it whenever you need an entry set of specific index.

```
public static <String, Integer> Map.Entry<String, Integer> getEntryByIndex(Map<String, Integer> map, int i) {
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    for(; i > 0; --i) {
        it.next();
    }
    return it.next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand what I was doing wrong. But I am still getting error for getValue() and getKey() methods. Android Studio is saying it cannot resolve those symbols.